# Docker: run multiple scripts (containers) from the same image

Tags: python, docker

I made a Python project with several packages and several scripts that depend upon the packages. The structure looks something like this:

```
app/
  package1/
    __init__.py
    ...
  package2/
    __init__.py
    ...
  script1.py
  script2.py
```

So I dockerized the app, that is, I made an image with some Dockerfile, wherein the default script is, say, script1.py:

```
FROM ...
ADD ...
...
CMD python script1.py
```

My question: is it a good practice to start two different containers from this single image, one that runs scrip1, the other for script2?

```
docker build -t my_image .
docker run -d -it my_image
docker run -d -it my_image python script2.py
```

Note that, in my case, script1 and script2 are independent of one another (they do not communicate and can be started independently).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Questions about "good practice" do not belong on stack overflow, since they typically just boil down to subjective taste and opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#avoid-installing-unnecessary-packages) lists as a best practice that "Each container should have only one concern".  In your example it sounds as though you effectively have two tasks being ran by the two separate Python scripts, but packaged within the same image.

Ideally you would avoid this and have two separate images for your two tasks.  If the two scripts share a large number of common dependencies you could create your own parent image to base the two script images on.